# ORDS - Oauth Implicit grant-type issue

Tags: oauth, oracle-apex, oracle-ords

I'm facing an issue using the Oauth IMPLICIT authentification for ORDS, hope someone can help me there.

I followed this documentation : [text](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/oracle-rest-data-services-ords-authentication#oauth2-authorization-code)

When I try to get my refresh-token with : https://***.***.***/ords/***/oauth/auth?response_type=token&client_id=**********..&state=3668D7A713E93372E0406A38A8C02171

I land on a 401 - Unauthorized, I log in ORDS with my credentials
Then i'm redirected to a 400 - Bad Request : Parameter value is missing or incorrect : client_id

I tried to delete my user an restart the procedure several times, it seems like I did something wrong or missed in the documentation ...

I'm using Oracle APEX 23.2.0

Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you make sure that you use the correct client ID that you registered at the server beforehand?

Comment: Hello, yes I did check multiple times that the client_id was the right one, thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like there might be an issue with how you're passing the client_id parameter in your OAuth authentication request. The error message "Parameter value is missing or incorrect: client_id" suggests that the client_id parameter is either missing or not correctly formatted.

Here are a few things you can double-check:

**Client ID Format**: Ensure that the client_id parameter is correctly formatted. It should be provided as part of the URL query string and should match the client ID assigned to your OAuth client application in ORDS.

**URL Encoding:** Make sure that the client_id parameter value is properly URL encoded if it contains any special characters. URL encoding ensures that special characters are correctly interpreted by the server.

**Client Registration:** Verify that the OAuth client application is properly registered in ORDS with the correct client_id. Double-check the client registration settings to ensure that they match the parameters you're using in your authentication request.

**Permissions and Scopes:** Ensure that the OAuth client application has the necessary permissions and scopes configured in ORDS to access the requested resources. Lack of appropriate permissions could result in authentication failures.

Logging and Debugging: Check the ORDS logs for any additional error messages or debugging information that could provide insights into why the client_id parameter is not being recognized or accepted.

---

If you've verified the above and are still encountering issues, it might be helpful to provide more specific details about how you're constructing the authentication request and any relevant configuration settings in ORDS. Additionally, reviewing the ORDS documentation or seeking assistance from the Oracle community forums or support channels could also provide valuable insights into resolving the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply ! I'm not sure about the URL encoding, I will try but I saw some videos and they are not encoding anything. For the client registration to check my client_id I do : select * from user_ords_clients. I don't understand the link between the Apex/Ords account, I log to when I hit the 401 - Unauthorized and the client_id. Do I need to link them somehow ?